# 'Unexpected token' when using colon in json name and JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to run the below code but continue to get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` error in the console. I can not seem to escape the colon in the json name.

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"first:Name":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"first:Name":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"first:Name":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
text.employees[1].first:Name ;

</script>
```

Any help to resolve this would be great. Ultimately the JSON will be coming from a web response so can not change the text.

Comment: Try removing : from first:Name and check ..

Comment: Try `obj.employees[1]['first:Name']`

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text.employees[1].first:Name;
                                                                   ^__error here
```

#### Use string representation of object property

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text.employees[1]['first:Name']
```

#### or remove `:` from you object

```
{"first:Name":"John","lastName":"Doe" }
       ^___ is this intentional?
```

Answer (score 0):

`text.employees[1].first:Name ;` is no valid JavaScript, you'll need to access the key like this:

`text.employees[1]['first:Name'];`

Answer (score 0):

You get `Unexpected token :` because JS was expected a dot notation when instead found a `:`.

You can solve this issue by using `bracket notation` in order to access the property `first:Name` for your object.

More information can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

You example fixed:

```js
var text = '{"employees":[' +
  '{"first:Name":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
  '{"first:Name":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
  '{"first:Name":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.employees[1]['first:Name'];
```

```html
<dv id="demo"></dv>
```